# Changing a username in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to give the user the ability to change their username in my application. I have tried the following code with no success, can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
@IBAction func Save(sender: AnyObject) {

    let name = nameField.text
    let username = usernameField.text
    let bio = bioField.text
    let location = locationField.text
    let website = websiteField.text

    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()

}
```

I get their username and password in a code block above.

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()!
nameField.text = user["fullname"] as! String
usernameField.text = user["username"] as! String
```

I thought that if I just got their information then changed the text in the text field and saved it that it would overwrite the information that is there now but I guess I am wrong (and possibly dumb). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never setting the new username in parse. All you are doing is setting the text field's text to what the current username is. Here is what you should do:

```
@IBAction func Save(sender: AnyObject) {

   let name = nameField.text
   let username = usernameField.text
   let bio = bioField.text
   let location = locationField.text
   let website = websiteField.text

   var user = PFUser.currentUser()!
   user["username"] = username
   //You can change more fields here, this just sets the new username.

   user.saveInBackground()

}
```